# .net: Create/store a big amount data paralleling to SQL server

Tags: .net, sql, database, parallel-processing

I'm going to create/save loads of records (30,000) to database tables in each batch. 
If I use paralleling programm for reducing the process time, how can I manage the following issues?

- the db tables will be blocked that the performance will not actually be as good as expected
- Is there any pattern I can take a reference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need  parallel processing? 30000 may not be *that* big. I suggest you look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class first. Here is a link that explains how to use it: [Using SqlBulkCopy To Perform Efficient Bulk SQL Operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927181836/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102109-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Simon. Frankly, I'm not sure if the parallel programming helps for my scenario. I'm afraid my question title is not clear enough either. The entire processing is more than storing data. It actually goes through a bit complex process and as part of the result, it generates the data and store them into a couple of tables

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, most database professionals wouldn't consider 30K records a large data set - are you sure you need to worry about performance?

Depending on a whole bunch of factors, database servers actually deal really well with multiple processes inserting/updating data in the same table - it's kind of their primary purpose in life. I'm assuming you do mean a DB server product like MS SQL Server, Oracle or MySQL.

Simon Mourier's suggesting of BulkCopy is probably the fastest way of banging a large data set into a table.

If you do need to run parallel processing, the key is transaction management - if each thread starts a transaction and doesn't commit it for a long time, you may run into locking issues. Read up on your database's implementation, and try to have short-running transactions.